# What is the retry logic to int-http:outbound-gateway?

Tags: spring-integration

I have a int-http:outbound-gateway in my spring integration config file that consumes a rest service.
I am trying to start the error handling part of the implementation, but I would like first to understand how the retry works. I can notice that when an error occurs, let's say a bad request, spring integration framework seems to retry to send the request to the rest service and, in fact, depending on the error - http code - I would like to handle it in a different way.
How can I avoid the retry depending on the http response code?

Comment: No-op. There is no retry by default. Please, claim that with some test-case and logs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no inherent retry; retry is implemented using a [retry advice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain).

It can be customized for different exception types, but not for status codes; you would need a custom advice for that - the documentation explains how to write one.